# Calculated column ; count if

Tags: calculated-column, count

I'm trying to do a few "Count" function columns. 
I want to do a calculated column saying; count Column A if the field has a Yes entry.
I then want to say something similar; count Column A if the field has a value (not null)

Comment: what is your question? can you provide us real equation/state you want to put in calculated column? so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

The Excel COUNTIF does not work in SharePoint as it requires a range. As an alternate, do a test on each column that returns 1 or 0, and add the results.

```
=IF(col1="Yes",1,0) + IF(col2="Yes",1,0) + IF(col3="Yes",1,0)   ...
```

or count of non-blank columns:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(col1),0,1) + IF(ISBLANK(col2),0,1) + IF(ISBLANK(col3),0,1)  ...
```